# Get top values from Elasticsearch bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have some items with `brand`
I want to return `N` records, but no more than `x` from each bucket

So far I have my buckets grouped by `brand`

```js
  "aggs": {
    "brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand"
      }
    }
  }
```

```js
"aggregations" : {
    "brand" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "brandA",
          "doc_count" : 130
        },
        {
          "key" : "brandB",
          "doc_count" : 127
        }
      ]
    }
```

But how do I access specific bucket and get top x values from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)  sub aggregation  to get documents under each brand. You can sort those documents and define a size too.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "brand": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "brand",
        "size": 10 --> no of brands
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],            
            "size": 1 --> no of documents under each brand
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```